# Does docker offer 'reverse' isolation

Tags: security, docker

I'm looking for a way to protect a container from the regular userspace.

When I start a container I can

- see a lot of info about what happens inside (e.g. `ps` also shows pid's inside the container)
- make the container do whatever I want (e.g. `docker exec`).

Is it possible to launch a container in such a way that I can only

- Stop and remove (and maybe pause) the container but have no other control over it ?
- See the actions/effects of the container on the outside world (total used resources, TCP/IP packets leaving the container, ...) but not how those resources are used, how TCP/IP packets travel inside the container, ... ?

So what I actually want is the reverse of the usual isolation.

I can't find anything about this, not even in [the security part of the official documention](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/).

The most important reason for my question:
It would make it easier to protect containers against accidents happening in regular userspace.

Comment: The host always has total access to the container. It's not really feasible to do otherwise.